# Partial sum of harmonic series smaller than $\log n+1$

Tags: real-analysis

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for every $j\leq k$ hold that $2^j\leq n$ and $2^{k+1}> n$.

Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \leq k+1.$$

****Thoughts**** I know that $j\leq \log_2 n<k+1$ and probably $k=\log{n}$ but how I can use it in the sum?

Also I'm looking for a way without integrals so not sure Euler's constant can help.

Comment: Do you mean $n<2^{k+1}$?

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{1}{i}}  \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{2^{k + 1}  - 1} {\frac{1}{i}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^k {\sum\limits_{j = 2^i }^{2^{i + 1}  - 1} {\frac{1}{j}} }  < \sum\limits_{i = 0}^k {\sum\limits_{j = 2^i }^{2^{i + 1}  - 1} {\frac{1}{{2^i }}} }  = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^k 1  = k + 1
$$

Comment: Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n<2^{k+1}$. Without summation notation:

$$ \begin{array}{ll}
 & 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} \\
\le & 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1} \\
< & 1+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{2^k}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}) \\
= & 1+1+\cdots+1 \\
= & k+1.
\end{array} $$

Comment: So I can say $ k=\log n$?

Comment: @G.Ticher You can say $k=\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$.

Comment: @G.Ticher Note that this method gives the upper bound $
\left\lfloor {\log _2 (n)} \right\rfloor  + 1$ which is worse than $\log_e(n)+1$. To get $\log_e (n) +1$ you would need another approach.